# Python: Working out whitespace in date

Tags: python, datetime

I have a log file `file.txt` and it has the date format as `'%b %_d %H:%M:%S'`.
When the day of the month is between the 1st and 9th, it pads out the field with a space.

I'm just wondering if my code is the best way to check if this includes a space or not as I'm just trying to pull out the date/time from each line

file.txt

```
Sep  8 16:13:02 blah
Sep  8 16:14:02 blahblah
Sep  8 16:15:02 blablahblah
```

Code:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if int(line.split()[1]) < 10:
            d = line.split()[0] + '  ' + line.split()[1] + ' ' + line.split()[2] #double space after [0]
        else:
            d = line.split()[0] + ' ' + line.split()[1] + ' ' + line.split()[2] #single space after [0]
        print d
```

Comment: There's probably a better way to grab it into a timestamp/datetime variable, I'd continue looking if you really want to improve this..

Comment: datetime's [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) handles the extra space without issue: `print(datetime.strptime("Sep  8 16:13:02", '%b %d %H:%M:%S'))` (double space present, just hidden in HTML) -- just adjust the year after parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your output field to be padded with spaces, you can use python [string formatting spec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

```
>>> for line in 'Sep 8 16:13:02 blah', 'Sep 12 16:13:02 blah':
>>>     print('{0} {1:>2} {2}'.format(*line.split()))

Sep  8 16:13:02
Sep 12 16:13:02
```

`{1:>2}` means that field 1 should be right aligned and at least 2 characters wide. Missing characters will be padded with spaces.

In python 3.6+ you can also use f-strings to make it more self-explanatory.

```
>>> for line in 'Sep 8 16:13:02 blah', 'Sep 12 16:13:02 blah blah blah':
>>>     month, date, time, *rest  = line.split() 
>>>     print(f'date: {month} {date:>2} {time}\ncomment: {" ".join(rest)}')

date: Sep  8 16:13:02
comment: blah
date: Sep 12 16:13:02
comment: blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment by jedwards:

```
from datetime import datetime

f = '''Sep  8 16:13:02 blah
Sep  8 16:14:02 blahblah
Sep  8 16:15:02 blablahblah'''.splitlines()

for line in f:
    d = datetime.strptime(line[:15], '%b %d %H:%M:%S')
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
1900-09-08 16:13:02
1900-09-08 16:14:02
1900-09-08 16:15:02
```